# Cannot get data from dictionary python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have dictionary like this in variable balance

```
print(balance)

{'makerCommission': 10, 'takerCommission': 10, 
'balances': [
{'asset': 'A', 'free': '0.01'}, 
{'asset': 'B', 'free': '0.02'}, 
{'asset': 'C', 'free': '0.03'}]}
```

I want to get value free from B which is 0.02. I try with this code.

```
print(balance["balances"]['asset']['B'])
```

It show error.

> TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str

How to get data from dictionary ?

Comment: What does `print(balance["balances"])` produce?  Does that explain why your code didn't work, and suggest how to fix it?

Comment: The value of `balance['balances']` is `[{'asset': 'A', 'free': '0.01'}, {'asset': 'B', 'free': '0.02'}, {'asset': 'C', 'free': '0.03'}]`. Therefore, it has a structure of list. So, if you want to access `B`, then you should specify the accessing index. A suggested example is `balance['balances'][1]['asset']` so that the result will be `B`.

Comment: I think what you want to do is `balance["balances"][1]["free"]` because the `balances` key has an array of assets as its values, and b is the second element of that array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there will only ever be a single asset `'B'` in `balance['balances']`:

```
print(*[b['free'] for b in balance['balances'] if b['asset'] == 'B'])
```

Result:

```
0.02
```

If you just need the value in a variable:

```
list_free_for_b_assets = [b['free'] for b in balance['balances'] if b['asset'] == 'B']
```

Answer (score 0):

the value for the balances key is a list , so you have to access the list items by their index:

```
print(balance["balances"][1]["free"])

> 0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate over balances or index it. To get the contents of free.

```
balance["balances"][1]['free'] #'0.02'
```

or

```
for item in balance["balances"]:
    item['free'] # '0.01', '0.02', ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Python Dictionaries use `{}`'s.
Python Lists use `[]`'s.

Your master object has 3 fields: `makerComission` and `takerComission` which are both numbers, and `balances` which is a *list* of more JSON Objects. Thus, you must use numbers to access the *list*.

Comment: The question is about Python lists and dictionaries, not JSON.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).